tkinter window not working with GPIO touch screen
I'm using a raspberry pi zero 2 W with a 3.5 inch GPIO touch screen display. (http://www.lcdwiki.com/3.5inch_RPi_Display)
The issue I am running into is that a GUI I am making using the Tkinter library makes the touch screen "bug" and place the cursor far away compared to where I am clicking on the screen.
The pi is running the latest raspberry pi os (debian bookworm port).
On the desktop and other functions of the pi, the touch screen works perfectly fine.
It is just when I am on the tkinter window, the touch screen's clicks are significantly inaccurate.
Additionally, I am using RPi.GPIO to control pins on the board, however other tkinter GUIs that do not use the RPi library also bug.
I'm happy to post code or explain more.
Tried changing how I defined the geometry of the window, and changed whether it was windowed or not. Haven't looked into the touch screen code, but presumably that will be the next step. Or maybe some random setting I set on the tkinter window.

Have you confirmed the driver installation and calibration of the touch screen?

I ended up wiping the SD card and redownloading the OS and touch screen drivers  and it started working fine... no idea what caused Tkinter to not play nice with the touch screen originally.
